# Fail to link a static lib in a makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile, linker, clang, nasm

i'm doing a static library in asm and i'm trying to use its fonctions after in a c main.
I don't understand why, during the **make test rule**, the linkage doesnt work since i checked the library dir with **-L.** and the include dir with **-I ./include**, as well as the lib itself with **-static and -lasm**

What can i change ?

Here is my Makefile :

```
NAME = libasm.a

SRC =           ft_write.s \
                ft_read.s \
                ft_strcmp.s \
                ft_strcpy.s \
                ft_strdup.s \
                ft_strlen.s

SRC_BONUS =     ft_atoi_base.s \
                ft_list_push_front.s \
                ft_list_size.s \
                ft_list_sort.s \
                ft_list_remove_if.s

SRC_DIR = ./srcs

CC = clang
CFLAGS = -v  -L. -I$(INCLUDE) -static -Wall -Wextra -Werror -lasm

NASM = nasm
NASMFLAGS = -f elf64

INCLUDE = ./include

OBJ_DIR = ./objs
OBJ = $(patsubst %.s, ${OBJ_DIR}/%.o, ${SRC})
OBJ_BONUS = $(OBJ) $(patsubst %.s, ${OBJ_DIR}/%.o, ${SRC_BONUS})

BIN = test

all : $(NAME)

$(NAME) : $(OBJ)
        ar rcs $@ $^
        ranlib $(NAME)
        @echo "$(NAME) has been created"

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.s
        mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
        @echo "\033[0;32mGenerating binary..."
        $(NASM) $(NASMFLAGS) $< -o $@
        @echo "\033[0m"

test : main.c $(NAME)
        $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN)
        ./$(BIN)

bonus : $(OBJ_BONUS)
        ar rcs $(NAME) $^
        ranlib $(NAME)
        @echo "$(NAME) with bonus has been created"

clean :
        rm -f $(OBJ_BONUS)

fclean : clean
        rm -f $(NAME)
        rm -f $(BIN)
```

and the trace : the problem is the undefined reference (référence indéfinie)

```
clang main.c -v -g -L. -I./include -static -Wall -Wextra -Werror -lasm -o test
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.c -static-define -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=limited -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.0 -I ./include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -Wall -Wextra -Werror -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/salty/Documents/libasm -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 106 -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /tmp/main-559408.o -x c main.c
clang -cc1 version 6.0.0 based upon LLVM 6.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 ./include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu -m elf_x86_64 -static -o test /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/crtbeginT.o -L. -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../.. -L/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/main-559408.o -lasm --start-group -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc --end-group /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/main-559408.o : Dans la fonction « check_strlen » :
libasm/main.c:13 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_strlen »
/tmp/main-559408.o : Dans la fonction « check_strcmp » :
libasm/main.c:22 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_strcmp »
/tmp/main-559408.o : Dans la fonction « check_strdup » :
libasm/main.c:33 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_strdup »
/tmp/main-559408.o : Dans la fonction « strdup_test » :
libasm/main.c:42 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_strdup »
/tmp/main-559408.o : Dans la fonction « check_strcpy » :
libasm/main.c:61 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_strcpy »
libasm/main.c:64 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_strcpy »
/tmp/main-559408.o : Dans la fonction « strcpy_test » :
libasm/main.c:75 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_strcpy »
libasm/main.c:94 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_strcpy »
libasm/main.c:98 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_strcpy »
/tmp/main-559408.o:/home/salty/Documents/libasm/main.c:102 : encore plus de références indéfinies suivent vers « ft_strcpy »
/tmp/main-559408.o : Dans la fonction « list_size_test » :
libasm/main.c:176 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_list_size »
/tmp/main-559408.o : Dans la fonction « list_sort_test » :
libasm/main.c:242 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_list_sort »
/tmp/main-559408.o : Dans la fonction « list_push_front_test » :
libasm/main.c:264 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_list_push_front »
/tmp/main-559408.o : Dans la fonction « list_remove_if_test » :
libasm/main.c:287 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_list_remove_if »
/tmp/main-559408.o : Dans la fonction « atoi_base_test » :
libasm/main.c:297 : référence indéfinie vers « ft_atoi_base »
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Makefile:61: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

And also the dir tree:

```
./
├── include
│   └── libasm.h
├── libasm.a
├── main.c
├── Makefile
├── objs
│   ├── ft_atoi_base.o
│   ├── ft_list_push_front.o
│   ├── ft_list_remove_if.o
│   ├── ft_list_size.o
│   ├── ft_list_sort.o
│   ├── ft_read.o
│   ├── ft_strcmp.o
│   ├── ft_strcpy.o
│   ├── ft_strdup.o
│   ├── ft_strlen.o
│   └── ft_write.o
└── srcs
    ├── ft_atoi_base.s
    ├── ft_list_push_front.s
    ├── ft_list_remove_if.s
    ├── ft_list_size.s
    ├── ft_list_sort.s
    ├── ft_read.s
    ├── ft_strcmp.s
    ├── ft_strcpy.s
    ├── ft_strdup.s
    ├── ft_strlen.s
    └── ft_write.s
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have not given us [enough information to reproduce the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but are you sure that this makefile produces a file named `libasm.a`?

Comment: What is the output from `nm libasm.a | grep ' ft_strlen'`?